# Webview in Android app is not showing JPG images but PNG works

Tags: android, image, webview, png, jpeg

Webview in Android app is not showing JPG images but there is no problem with showing PNG images.

Here is the code for PNG (working)

`<img src="dir/image.PNG">`

for JPG (not working)

`<img src="dir/image.JPG">`

---

#### Solved

That was a format problem. I used standard PNG to JPG converter.

Comment: Try to put the `.JPG` as background instead of `src`

Comment: try changing .jpg file. Could be that the one you are setting is corrupted

Comment: @Metalhead1247 I don't want to do that because of the text data has to be displayed on the Webview

Comment: @LazyNinja I have tried with that. Is there something more in Webview to be set for JPG files? PNGs are easily displayed, I have tried same images to convert PNG into JPG also. but didnt work.

Comment: @HariOmPrakash try with  different jpg images and check

Comment: @Metalhead1247 Sir, I have tried with many jpg images also.

Comment: @HariOmPrakash are you getting error or it is setting to blank?

Comment: Are you using webview? Why not an imageview ?

Comment: @LazyNinja You trick works! Thanks

Comment: @HariOmPrakash src takes only .png images so u need to convert jpg to png